# JPA/Hibernate: mapping a one to many relation to hashmap using part of embedded id as key (without join table)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am stuck on the following problem:

I have an entity with an embedded composite id. This entity is used as the 'many' in a one to many relationship. I want to refer to this relationship on the 'one' side with a Map, where the key is one attribute of the embedded id, and the value is the entity itself (see code below for clarification).

I have tried several combinations of ElementCollection, JoinColumn, MapKeyColumn and MapKeyJoinColumn annotations, both the JPA and hibernate specific ones, but cannot get it to work. Maybe this is just not possible with an embedded id?

```
@Entity
public class Item {

    @Column 
    private Long id;

    //Which annotations to use here?
    private Map<Team, TeamStatus> statusses;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Team { 
    @Column 
    private Long id;    
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class TeamStatus {   
    @EmbeddedId 
    private ItemTeamPk itemTeamPk;

    @Column 
    private Boolean statusFlag;
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
public class ItemTeamPk {

    @ManyToOne
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne
    private Item item;
}
```

EDIT: note I am using JPA 2.1

Errors I get:

Using

```
@javax.persistence.OneToMany
@javax.persistence.MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "itemTeamPk.team")
private Map<Team, TeamStatus> teamStatusses;
```

gives

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "ITEM_TEAMSTATUS" not found
```

Same when using team_id, itemTeamPk.team_id or any other value as name.
Same error also occurs when using:

```
@javax.persistence.OneToMany
@javax.persistence.MapKey(name = "itemTeamPk")
private Map<Team, TeamStatus> teamStatusses ;
```

Comment: Do you get any exception? If yes please provide it.

Comment: You have a composite id but only want to use part of it as a map key? That seems weird since either you could end up having multiple entities being mapped to the same key (if you have multiple status elements for the same team and different items - which should be put into your map?) or that part of the id is already unique and thus there's no need for the other parts.

Comment: Btw, since you're using JPA 2 you should be able to remove `ItemTeamPk` and put `team`, `item` and `statusFlag` directly into `TeamStatus` each annotated with `@Id`. You'd then need `@IdClass(ACorrespondingClass.class)`   for query purposes.

Comment: @Patrick; I  updated the question

Comment: @Thomas statusFlag should ofcourse be part of the TeamStatus entity, my mistake. The composite (Item, Team) is unique, so for any Item there will be only one TeamStatus per team

Comment: Hmm, think of how Hibernate would see it: you're telling it the key consists of 2 elements and thus there might be multiple statusses for the same team but different items.